# How can I write a SQL query to produce a count of each value seen in a particular column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I have the following SQL query:

```
select * from sval where fid = 4052 and id in (select blah blah blah)));
```

And this produces:

```
    id      fid          timestamp           val  
403120126   4052    2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 FMUS
403120127   4052    2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 FMEE
403120136   4052    2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 FMUS
403120141   4052    2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 FMRU
403120170   4052    2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 FMUS
403120183   4052    2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 FMRU
403120188   4052    2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 FMEE
403120207   4052    2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 FMHK
```

I am trying to get a count of each value seen in the `val` column. Is this possible?

So for the above, I would ideally like to have:

```
val    count 
FMUS     3
FMEE     2
FMRU     2
FMHK     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT val
,Occurrences = COUNT(val)
FROM sval
WHERE ...
GROUP BY val
```

You just want to count the occurrences of each value, then a simple `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` works.